# Setting up git branches

Tags: git

Hi I have setup git on my local machine.

So I can now fully develop locally and push my files to master origin.

but I'd like to be able to commit my files from local to a stage folder on remote, and then from there create a branch with all the files that goes to production. any ideas on how i can establish this
? I am very new to git. (just learned hot to commit, that new lol)

Comment: Create the new branch locally, then push the branch to a remote. (See here: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches#Pushing)

Answer (score 0):

You don't really on your remote. You make changes locally and push them to the remote. So in your case, you set the branches up the way you want in your local repository and push the ones you want to to the remote.